# SMS_READ BroadcastReceiver not working from certain phones?

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver, sms

This is an odd one.  I have written a simple app to actually solve a communication problem for my wife and I during the day.  The app is simple...but it solves the problem.  To work effectively, the app required SMS_READ and SMS_RECEIVE permissions as well as SEND_SMS.

This is not a text messaging app, but the core of the app is automated SMS to and from our phones.

I have a very simple BroadcastReceiver registered which listens for incoming messages and does different things based on keywords received in the text message.

Which this said...the app works GREAT if I'm testing from my own phone or sending myself messages from a Google Voice number on voice.google.com for example.

If my WIFE tries to send me a message, the BroadcastReceiver never fires.  I cannot for the life of my figure out why.

I know Google has locked down SMS permissions but this is not for Google Play Store.  This is just for my phone and my wife's phone.

Again...if I'm on my own phone and I send a text to myself...works great.  BroadcastReceiver fires...does it's thing.  If I send myself a text from my google voice number via the Google Voice website...works great.

If I send a text from my wife's phone?  No dice.  Nothing.  Android logs show nothing of any interest.  No errors...just doesn't fire.

My phone - Samsung Note 10
Wife's phone - Google Pixel 4

I'd love some advice if anyone has any.  Following if any relevant code I can think of.

I'm registering the receiver in my manifest and requesting all permissions.

First the manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.YouAndMeApp">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.YouAndMeApp">
    
            <activity
                android:name=".FoundIt"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_found_it"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.YouAndMeApp.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
            <receiver
                android:name=".SmsReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
                <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> 
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    
            <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

My receiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {

                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                String str = "";
                String sender = "";
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        str += msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        sender += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    }
                }

                MainActivity.sender = sender;

                SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String storedPin = prefs.getString("pin", "");

                if (str.equals(storedPin)) {
                    try {
                        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), FoundIt.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String msg = e.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception was thrown in SMSReceiver.java - " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and found an answer posted.  The message app is defaulting to chat via wifi data NOT SMS transport.  Turn off chat and wifi on relevant phones and uniform operation comes back.